# Why do wires shred when using a pull elbow?

Tags: electrical, wiring

When I fish my wires through the 1/2" emt conduit to the 90 degree pull elbow box outlet, the wire coverings are a little shredded. They are not kinked. Should I be concerned about the wire covering shredding? Or should I try it again using a pull elbow box that has opening? How do electricians do it if they weren't using an open cover?

Comment: Are you using THHN wire or have you shucked the sheath off Romex?   Are you popping the cover off the elbow and pulling from there, or are you dragging the wire around the elbow?

Comment: Did you debur the inside of the emt pipe real well?

Comment: I agree with Edwin on deburing the pipe many don't realise how important it is (I even do factory ends). If deburred have some one push the wire while pulling. The covering is for protection while being pulled in and it gets damaged regularly but if there is any damage to the insulation itself it would fail inspection.

Comment: @Harper thnn wire but used a regular box elbow. I thought i deburrrd -- no sharp edges around the inside of pipe.

Comment: I was puzzled when you mentioned the elbow. They should be irrelevant to the pull, since you can only start or end a pull at one, and they give you a fairly straight shot down the pipe. Needless to say **you can't pull around elbows.**  That's why they have lids.

Comment: Is this a prefab 90 or did you bend it yourself. If you bent it yourself other, than the deburring everyone has mentioned, if you kinked or left dimples in your 90 that could shred some insulation. Generally when you pull and shred wire it is a tough pull. Try pulling with a wire lubrication. Yellow 77 or Polywater are the two I'm familiar with.

Comment: @Harper sorry i didn't know. They had a 90 pull elbow box without a cover. Bought a new One with covering. See picture of old one with thnn wire shredded

Comment: There are fittings out there which give a [compact 90](https://www.bk-electric.com/2355792/Product/T&B_Ind_Fitting_4230), but they are *really* intended to be installed right at an accessible point where you can have one person carefully push to "baby" the wires around the bend while the other person pulls.  If you're trying to do a 1-person muscle-drag, it won't work, and that's why I won't use them.

Comment: Thank u for helping me. I corrected the pull elbow and rewired it. Larry

Answer (score 1):

## Don't pull my elbow!

Elbows cannot be pulled around as their radius is far tighter than a minimum radius bend.  Hence, you have to take the cover off, pull to the elbow enough wire for the rest of the run to form a "loop" there, and then continue the pull from the elbow to the rest of the run.

Comment: i did purchased a pull elbow with a cover and put new wires inside and after 10 wasted conduits, i achieved it.. the problem is if you have 1/2" conduit, all of the videos that i watched never answer my question. There are offset boxes which are not just raised, but lowered and  making perpidular offsets by turning the conduit in the shoe. Any video books that show this. Ugly's only shows you basically bending conduit that is straight (up and down not around not snaking aroung an object or an oppposite 90 degree bend instead of a back to back.Are there any video books out there?

Answer (score 0):

The name of the part doesn't imply you can pull around the elbow. It means you can pull the wires out of the inspection caver and assist them around the corner with a loop like the previous poster said.